# Asp.NET Get current domain

Tags: .net, asp.net, dns

If I have a website running at `www.example.com`, but someone accesses it by IP address. How can I in code lookup in IIS that `www.example.com` is the actual site's domain?

Comment: An ASP.NET app doesn't know anything about the configuration of the container it's hosted in. To access the IIS configuration, your ASP.NET app would need to be running at elevated privileges which is a huge no-no, not to mention the wrong way to go about what you're trying to do. What you should be doing is redirecting any requests accessing the site by anything other than its canonical name. Then you don't have to worry about this. Please describe more about why you feel the need to do this.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific. What you're saying is "How can I know my name if someone says "Hey you"? Of course you know your name, and your website should know its name as well. Your question does not make a lot of sense on the surface, unless there is something more you're not saying.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. This is for a licensing issue that allows sites by domain name but if someone hits the site by ip address it can't find the domain name so licensing fails.

Comment: In that case, the responsibility falls on the customer to make sure all requests are canonicalized or buy separate licenses for the additional domains. SiteFinity (among many others I'm sure) uses a per-domain licensing model, and the same issue applies to their stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to **reliably** look up a domain based on an IP address because an IP address can be mapped to 0 or more domain names.

The best you can do is have a list of mappings.  Note that it's also possible for a local network IP address and an external IP point to the same location.

In general, a specific machine can be referenced by several IPs, each of which can be referenced by several domains.  So you can go `domain > IP address -> machine` but not the other way around.

Comment: I think you mean it's not possible to "reliably" look up a domain based on IP.  It's certainly possible, but it may not be the right domain name, and most sites don't have proper reverse dns records anyways.

Comment: Not true... I have posted how to do it although it might not be 100%.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to get the IP of `www.example.com` so you can compare it?

You can get the IP of `www.example.com` by doing:

```
 System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("www.example.com").AddressList[0].ToString();
```

You could then compare the IPs to see if they are the same.  Also note that there is a list so you could check to see if it exists:

```
bool ipMatch = (System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("www.example.com").
    AddressList.Where(a => a.ToString().Equals(userIP)).Count() > 0);
```

You could use `Contains` but then you have to build up an `IPAddress` object which you probably don't have.

**EDIT:** From your comment you have the IP and want the host address so just do:

```
string hostname = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(yourIPHere).HostName;
```

Comment: If I get the current domain from asp.net when a user hits the site by ip, I get the ipaddress, but what I'd like is the actual domain name. So if I get http://22.23.24.25/Default.aspx, I'd like to know that it's really http://www.bob.com/Default.aspx.

Comment: Why would you even need to look at the hostname?  You should already know you're bob.com. The only time you wouldn't is if it was a user configurable domain name, like a CMS or other generic application, in which case you would need some configuration entry to tell it what your name will be.

Comment: @Mystere Man I've learned to never ask why... everyone seems to have reasons to do almost anything ;)

Comment: +1 didn't know about `System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry`.  Although it won't work in all cases.  For example, `74.125.225.80` is Google (or at least one of Google's IP's) but GetHostEntry didn't find it.

Comment: Doesn't work for microsoft.com (207.46.197.32) either, that one actually threw a `SocketException` "No such host is known".  It worked for our company's website address though.

Comment: The component that needs to know is a licensing dll that validates a site by domain. If someone hits the site by ip address, the licensing dll can't validate the site even though it's still legitiment.